# Mysql Querying num of comment related to article

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, count, sum

I am trying to run a query to select the article that have the most comments related to the article id.

i have a article table and a comments table the comments table has a article_id field that links them and i am trying to do a left join here is want i have so far.

```
SELECT *, SUM(`comments`.`article_id`) AS total FROM (`articles`) JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` GROUP BY `comments`.`article_id` ORDER BY `total` asc
```

i am using CodeIgniter and the above is the output from my active record which is below.

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('articles');
        $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.article_id = articles.id');
        $this->db->group_by('comments.article_id');
        $this->db->select_sum('comments.article_id', 'total');
        $this->db->order_by('total', 'asc'); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
```

Ok this works i seem to be getting the correct output but i dont get the number of comments as a value which i need to work from.

so i want to get

article with id 1
has 23 comments

article with id 2
has 3 comments

etc etc

at the moment i am getting a sum of the article ids i think i have a total field with really high values which are not correct can some help with this???

Thanks

SORRY ANSWERED MY OWN QUESTION IM USING SUM AND NOT COUNT AARRRRRGGGGHHHH this works

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`comments`.`article_id`) AS total FROM (`articles`) JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` GROUP BY `comments`.`article_id` ORDER BY `total` asc
```

Comment: Since you solved the problem by yourself, post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I think still you won't get because you are counting article id's in your comments table.

Comment: If you already did what you are looking for, then answer your owen question with your answer. Then accept it. Just like that.

Comment: hey Mahmoud do u think the answer is correct........

Comment: @Venkat - Actually, I didn't understand his question.

Comment: He wants to count no of comments against one article id. Where he has two tables comments and articles. To join both of them he is using article_id column as a joint condition. He is counting comments.article_id in count function. So it will result no of article ids obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer..

SELECT articles.*, count(`comments`.`article_id`) AS total1 
FROM 
`articles` JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`article_id` 
GROUP BY `articles`.`article_id` ORDER BY `total1` asc

Comment: how it will come count(comments.article_id)...........it mean in comments table article_id's. Are you getting answer correctly

Comment: hi Venkat im sure its correct its returning the right results for me.

Comment: how it will give correct result when you are counting article_ids in comments table where you want total no of comments for an article _id. I think it should be count(comments.no_of_comments)

Comment: hi venkat turns out you was correct after a closer look they are wrong this worked for me "SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total FROM (`articles`) JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` GROUP BY `comments`.`article_id` ORDER BY `total` desc" can you suggest a better way to do this???

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are doing sum of article id's in your query. You need to calculate sum of comments. Remove article id in sum function put like this SUM(comments.comments_column_name). I mean in which column you are saving comments against each id in your comments table.